# Как из БД передать конкретные данные в тг бота

Tags: python, mysql, sql, aiogram

подскажите, пожалуйста ,как можно из БД передать данные моему тг боту.
У меня есть FSM, которая при нажатии на админ команду "добавление товара" задаёт мне вопросы по которым я задаю своему новому товару нужные параметры (в данном боте я передаю данные кроссовок. Модель, цена, бренд, фото), после FSM записывает все параметры в переменные и вставляет их в БД. На скрине БД вы видите что у меня в БД записаны два бренда кроссовок (найк и адидас). Вопрос в том, как при нажатии кнопки nike вывести из БД данные про найк, а при нажатии кнопки adidas вывести данные из БД про адидас.

Код БД:

```
async def db_start():
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS items("
                "i_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                "model TEXT,"
                "price INTEGER,"
                "photo_it TEXT,"
                "brang TEXT)")
    db.commit()


def db_table_items(model: str, price: int, brang: str, photo_it: str):
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO items (model, price, brang, photo_it) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
                   (model, price, brang, photo_it))
```

Код конца FSM:

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Form.photo, content_types=types.ContentType.PHOTO)
async def process_text(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        photo_item = data['photo'\] = message.photo[-1].file_id
    send_shoes = f"brend: {data['brend']}\n" 
    f"model: {data['model']}\n" \
    f"price: {data['price']}"
    brend_item  = f"brend: {data['brend']}"
    model_item = f"model: {data['model']}"
    price_item = f"price: {data['price']}"
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, send_shoes)
    await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=photo_item)
    db.db_table_items(brang=brend_item, price=price_item, model=model_item, photo_it=photo_item)
    await state.finish()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так же и вывести, sql запросом с использованием оператора `SELECT`